# What makes CyanogenMod in DDMS allow heap dumps regarless of their debug flag?

Tags: java, android, debugging, ddms, heap-dump

I have been searching for hours and cannot find the answer. CyanogenMOD ROM lets you dump the heap of ANY process, DDMS shows EVERY process when you plug the device in. How can I make a stock rom hold the same power? I have root on the device, and I have to hide it from the apps in a special way, otherwise I would flash a custom ROM. What makes a device spill its guts to DDMS when loaded with a custom ROM? I could set debug flag on app and rebuild, but I don't want to trip the tamper detection, and mitigate that protection measure.

Example:
I plug in my stock device (Galaxy Tab 2 7") and not one process shows up in DDMS. Plug in cyanogen (Galaxy S3) device and it shows everything and allows heap dumps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a ROM developer so my guess is just as good as yours, but this sounds like they probably implemented it in their custom kernel, not on the application level. So not really something you can do yourself, unless someone ported the feature over to a kernel for your ROM as well.

Comment: I am actually currently doing research to port some features to nexus kernels, since I have access to the devices, and I can get source.

Answer (score 0):

After spending more time in the Android system, when each app_process is started, the zygote will open a socket to JDWP (which you can forward through adb using the PID of your app) if the debug flag in the manifest is true, or when ro.debuggable is true in build.prop. So if you have a developer operating system, it treats every new app as a debug app. Typing "adb jdwp" into your shell should show you all the PIDS that have a JDWP socket ready. The interesting thing is, when you type that command in CM, it never gives you a shell back, so automating this required you to time it out.